# speedbar "display buffers" on startup

Tags: emacs

I would like to start the speedbar with the "Display Buffers" instead of "Display Files" option on startup.

```
(setq speedbar-mode-hook (lambda ()
  (interactive)
  (other-frame 0)))
(when window-system
  (speedbar t))
```

Comment: Please don't quote your lambdas, especially in online examples, where other users tend to then take up and perpetuate this bad habit.

Comment: this is a copy from the emacswiki, the lambda is quoted there too: https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SpeedBar

Comment: See this related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30722147/2112489